# Android SQLite Query - To Search the words which starts with any digit

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am newbie to the android development.

Can please any one let me know what is the query syntax to find out all the words which starts with any digit.

I had using the following syntax but it not works for me:

```
select * from TableName where ColumnName like '[0-9]%';
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`glob`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#glob) to get slightly more expressive power than with `like`, without needing to resort to `regexp` user functions:

```
... WHERE ColumnName GLOB '[0-9]*';
```

Comment: GLOB seems to be a good way to do limited pattern matching like the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

By default SQLite doesn't support regular expression. You got to mention it.

```
SELECT <column_names> FROM table_name WHERE column_name REGEXP '[0-9]%'
```

**REGEXP is supported on SQL and SQLite 3+; all of Android uses 3.5.9 or higher.**

**And one note to you, do not mention * in select statements, Mention column names you actually require.**

Comment: `REGEXP` is a shorthand for the `regexp()` user function which likely isn't defined. Also `[0-9]%` is not the right regexp to use.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite3 supports the REGEXP operator:

WHERE x REGEXP

select * from TableName where ColumnName REGEXP '[0-9]%';

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY CAST(value AS INTEGER);
```